# imacros select text on page

Tags: firefox, imacros

I'm just need to select text on the page.

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#post-3175>DIV>H2" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#imacros-highlight-div" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#imacros-highlight-div" BUTTON=0
```

This does not work,The text is only outlined.

Comment: Define "select". As in highlight it, or get it into your variable for use?

Comment: Only highlight it. Is it possible in imacros ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below highlights the element 'h2' outlined with 'iMacros'.

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#post-3175>DIV>H2" BUTTON=0

SET S "var doc = window.document;"
ADD S "var rng = doc.createRange();"
ADD S "var elsSel = doc.getElementsByTagName('h2');"
ADD S "for (i = 0; i < elsSel.length; i++) {"
ADD S "if (elsSel[i].style.outline == '1px solid blue') {"
ADD S "rng.selectNodeContents(elsSel[i]);"
ADD S "sel = window.getSelection();"
ADD S "sel.addRange(rng);"
ADD S "break; }}"

URL GOTO=javascript:{eval("{{S}}")}
```

Comment: Excellent! This is just what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do manually, double click it, using DBLCLICK :

```
EVENT TYPE=DBLCLICK SELECTOR="#post-3175>DIV>H2"
```